# PHP: Get all the dates in the weeks base on given date

Tags: php, datetime

hello there I have this code who will get the days of the week from the given date

```
<?php
$items = array();
// set current date
$datee = '11/01/2018';
// parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp 
$ts = strtotime($datee);
// calculate the number of days since Monday
$dow = date('w', $ts);
$offset = $dow - 1;
if ($offset < 0) {
    $offset = 6;
}
// calculate timestamp for the Monday
$ts = $ts - $offset*86400;
// loop from Monday till Sunday 
for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++, $ts += 86400){
    if($i==0){
        $sunday = date("m/d/Y l", $ts);
    }else if($i==5){
        $saturday = date("m/d/Y l", $ts) . "\n";
    }
}
echo $saturday;
echo $sunday;
?>
```

This code starts on monday and end on next sunday, But what I am trying to achieve is that start on sunday and then end on sunday my expected dates should be:

10/28/18(sunday) and 11/03/18(saturday)

what should I change here?

Comment: You must have tried something?

Comment: @Andreas what something?

Comment: How about changing some code?

Comment: I don't know what part to change? can you help me I am new to this date time manipulation

Comment: you should read up on DateInterval objects in PHP, I think that would be the best way to approach this

Comment: There is comments in the code explaining every part of it. https://3v4l.org/XQrhd

Answer (score 0):

Change `$offset = $dow - 1;` where the 1 represents the 2nd day of the week being Monday to `$offset = $dow - 0;` because Sunday is the 1st day of the week as returned by the date() function, then change the comments from Monday to Sunday, etc. 86400 represents the number of seconds in one day (24h*60m*60s).